driver LAN Card for Fanless G8-6157U
I just bought a fanless embedded PC type G8-6157U. Then I installed Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS but was hampered by the LAN port not working. Is there a driver solution to be able to activate the LAN port, because both of the  2 LAN ports don't work?

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's standard support life thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm  This is community support; 16.04 is EOSS thus out of community support.

To be clear it has been out of support on this site since April 30th 2021. Is there a reason you installed this ancient release?
